# Brushing Up on Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Struggling with a simple proof: Let $X = \{3^n\mid n > 0\}$ and $Y = \{3n\mid n \geq 0\}$. Prove that $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

I tried Direct Approach and Contrapositive, but I'm not strong enough with my proof skills yet. Can someone show me some steps to doing this? I don't need a direct solution, just some steps to get me in the right direction so I have a good example.

Comment: Hint: Assume that you have an element $x \in X$, and then show that $x$ must also be an element of $Y$.

Comment: My idea is, since 3^n is simple 3*3*3*... n times, there must be a way to convert this to something that looks like 3n.

Comment: @mrp that doesn't really make sense... that would imply $n=1$ or $n = .826018$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to know a few basic things.

1. Firstly, to prove $X \subseteq Y$, you can instead consider fixed but arbitrary $x \in X$, and prove that $x \in Y$.
2. Secondly, you need to know how to rewrite $\{f(x) \mid x \in X\}$ into a more useful form. Here's how you do it: assume $f : Y \leftarrow X$ is a function. Then:
   $$\{f(x) \mid x \in X\} = \{y \in Y \mid \exists x \in X, y=f(x)\}.$$

   The form on the right tends to be more useful than the one on the left.

Okay, so lets prove $X \subseteq Y$. We know that:

- $X = \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists a \in \mathbb{N} : k=3^a \;\&\; a>0 \}$
- $Y = \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists a \in \mathbb{N} : k=3a\}$

So consider $k \in X$, and fix some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k=3^a$ and $a>0.$ To show that $k \in Y$, we need to find $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k=3b$. That is, we're trying to find $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3^a=3b$. So toy with the equation $3^a = 3b$ until you've got $b$ in terms of $a$, and then prove rigorously that this choice of $b$ really does do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that if $x$ is an element of $X$, then $x$ is an element of $Y$ as well. Namely, if $x=3^n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N^+$, then there is some $k\in\Bbb N^+$ such that $x=3k$ (where $\Bbb N^+$ denotes the non-zero elements of $\Bbb N$, of course).

Can you think what $k$ should be?

Answer (score 0):

$$X=\left \{ {3^n|n>0} \right \} $$
$$X=\left \{ {3 \cdot 3^{n-1}|n \gt 0} \right \} $$
Let: $m=3^{n-1}$, $m>0$, for $n>0$ and is a subset of $\left \{n \geq 0 \right \}$,
$$X=\left \{ 3 \cdot m|m\in \left \{ n|n\geq 0\right \} \right \} $$